# XPath Select Siblings where sibling parent is root document

Tags: c#, xpath

I need to select the siblings of root and only for the first level.

I'm selecting html and it can be anyting...

ex:

```
<p><img...></p>
<p><img...></p>
<ul><li><a>somelink</a></li></ul>
<a>...
```

what i tryed was this `/*[following-sibling::*]` but that only selects the two `<p><img...></p>`...

what i want is to select the first level as in P P ul a.

Im useing Html Agillity Pack and my code looks like this:

```
        var nodeCollection = new List<HtmlNode>();
        var document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(html);

        if (document.DocumentNode != null)
        {
            foreach (var node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/*[following-sibling::*]"))
            {
                nodeCollection.Add(node);
            }
```

Anyone know what im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found a working xpath and it was not so hard xD
the following worked: `/child::*`